# using capitalize method right in formatting method in python

Tags: python, formatting, python-3.8, capitalize

```py
string_ = "hello world"
print("{0[1].capitalize()} {0[0].capitalize()}".format(string_.split(" ")))
```

with running this I get

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capitalize()'
```

please tell me what's wrong because string method has capitalize method in it!

```
dir(string_)
Out[108]: 
[...
 'capitalize',
 ...]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can only do that in f-strings; not in vanilla str.format.

Comment: @DeepSpace I think the format method isn't using the full parser, just splitting on dots.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, it might also use `getattr` but accidentally pass in the `()`, which is weird. For example, `getattr('a', 'capitalize()')` will of course generate the same error. It's a shame